# how to find the second derivative of the $\ln \frac{1-m^{x}}{x}$ at $x=0, m>1$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

I tried to write them as Taylor series, but then I obtain the series which is divergent.

Comment: As it's stated, the function is undefined at $x=0$. Now, it could be that the function is meant to be extended continuously in $x=0$ by setting $f(0)$ equal to the appropriate value, and that then you should calculate $f''(0)$ of *that* function...

Comment: What is $m$? If $m=0$ there is  no hope since you don't  even have continuity at $0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$y=\log \left(\frac{1-m^x}{x}\right)=\log(1-m^x)-\log(x)$$

$$\log(1-m^x)=\log (-\log (m))+\log (x)+\frac{1}{2} x \log (m)+\frac{1}{24} x^2 \log
   ^2(m)+O\left(x^4\right)$$
$$y=\log (-\log (m))+\frac{1}{2} x \log (m)+\frac{1}{24} x^2 \log
   ^2(m)+O\left(x^4\right)$$ Differentiate twice.

**Edit**

Around $x=0$
$$m^x=e^{x \log(m)}=1+x \log (m)+\frac{1}{2} x^2 \log ^2(m)+O\left(x^3\right)$$
$$1-m^x=-x \log (m)-\frac{1}{2} x^2 \log ^2(m)+O\left(x^3\right)$$
$$\log(1-m ^x)=\log (-\log (m))+\log (x)+\frac{1}{2} x \log (m)+O\left(x^2\right)$$

Comment: Can you explain, please, how you obtained the second raw?

Comment: @Bona. I shall edit.

Comment: @Bona. Is it OK now ?

Comment: Now from second equation when you took in both sides $\log $ then in right side you obtain $\log (−x \log(m)−\frac{1}{2 }(x \log(m))^2+O(x3)))$, how you obtain the third row?

Comment: The log of sum is not sum of log?